# Authentication in FastApi using oauth2 and jwt

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, openapi, fastapi

I am new to FastApi. I am trying to authenticate an user and redirect him to a protected endpoint. Upon giving the username and password (johndoe, secret) in /docs or /token, I am getting the authentication token. In the examples, they use cURL to "pass the token" with the request to a protected endpoint, but how do I do it during deployment?

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/view' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJqb2huZG9lIiwiZXhwIjoxNjE5MjEwMjYxfQ.g-NCbaEP0DzSw6FY1SQVHMlH3hzG3lTvWBkeJabuLwE'
```

The code below is from the tutorial.

```
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pydantic import BaseModel
from jose import JWTError, jwt
from typing import Optional


fake_users_db = {
    "johndoe": {
        "username": "johndoe",
        "full_name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@example.com",
        "hashed_password": "$2b$12$EixZaYVK1fsbw1ZfbX3OXePaWxn96p36WQoeG6Lruj3vjPGga31lW",
        "disabled": False,
    }
}


# openssl rand -hex 32
SECRET_KEY = "09d25e094faa6ca2556c818166b7a9563b93f7099f6f0f4caa6cf63b88e8d3e7"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30

app = FastAPI()

pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

# for css files
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str

class TokenData(BaseModel):
    username: Optional[str] = None

class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: Optional[str] = None
    full_name: Optional[str] = None
    disabled: Optional[bool] = None

class UserInDB(User):
    hashed_password: str


def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)

def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

def get_user(db, username: str):
    if username in db:
        user_dict = db[username]
        return UserInDB(**user_dict)

def authenticate_user(fake_db, username: str, password: str):
    user = get_user(fake_db, username)
    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
        return False
    return user

def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: Optional[timedelta] = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt

async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user

async def get_current_active_user(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user


@app.get("/token", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_login(request: Request):
    # login.html is a simple html form that takes in an username and a password
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

@app.get("/view"): # private endpoint. redirect here!
async def read_view(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return {"Neo": "We need guns. Lots of guns."}
```

In short, I want the server to authenticate (done) and redirect the user to a private endpoint and the browser to remember the token and pass it along whenever it requests a private endpoint. Sorry if this is silly!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

@app.get("/")
def read_view(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return RedirectResponse("/view")
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Fastapi underhood imports Starlette.response RedirectResponse class, which can be used to redirect to another adress as response of a Request

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/typer")
async def redirect_typer():
    return RedirectResponse(f'/your_view/')
```

or by this way using the response class parameter:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/fastapi", response_class=RedirectResponse, status_code=302)
async def redirect_fastapi():
    return f'/your_view/'
```

2- on the second step you will need update that redirect endpoint to use "scopes" with the oauth2 protocol, by this way you can mannage private endpoint and the scope for that endpoint of each type of user.

read this for more information:
[docs]: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/

3- Yo could store the access token in the client browser using localstorage or sessionstorage to perform the follow authenticated requests to your API

Some advices to consider when store access token on client browser are:

- Access Token does not contains sensitive information
- Use https protocol to request your API

follow this link to a better explain about store access token on the client browser:
[docs]: [Is is safe to store access token in session storage of client browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712395/is-is-safe-to-store-access-token-in-session-storage-of-client-browser)